# Accessing static classes in another java file

Tags: java, static-classes

Is it possible that I can access a static class in another *.java file?

My scenario is that I have two java files in the same folder, A.java and B.java:
In A.java, which does not only include class A but static class C:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          //code  
    }
    static class C{
        //code
    }
}
```

In B.java, which will use methods of class C:

```
public class B {    
     //code, use C's methods  
}
```

In the file B.java, I want to use class C's methods declared in the A.java; however, the compiler does not recognize the class C, even though I put the A.java and B.java in the same folder. I suppose I do not need to import anything because both java files are in the same folder, doesn't it? Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Just use `A.C.whatever()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that class `C` has no access modifier and will only be visible in the same package. To clarify: A subclass won't inherit access modifiers from its encapsulating class.

If `A` and `B` are on the same packages you can access `C` from `B` by using `A.C.<code>` If you would like to make `C` available to classes outside of `A`'s package you need to make the subclass `C` public:

```
// [...]
// insead of >>static class C {<<
public static class C {
// [...]
```

After you've changed the access modifier you can use `C` as mentioned above (`A.C.<code>`)

Comment: Thank you! It works. And I've got two questions:
1.I was told a rule that there is only one public class allowed to be in one *.java file because this public class  is needed to be the same as the name of java file. So is it good that there are two public class in one *.java file?
2.Why can't I use "import A.C.*;" in B.java instead of your method? I just tried and it did not work. But I am wondering the reason. If you could tell me, it would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. To your first question: Each .class-file (a compiled .java-file) needs to have exactly one "root"-class with the same name as the file. However you can have as many public subclasses you want inside this root class. To your second question: This is possible with a slightly different syntax. Instead of `import A.C.;` you need to use `import A.C;` (without the follwing `.`). In case `A` is in another package you need to specify it as well (for example: `import my.package.A.C;`).